# replacing strings in python

Tags: python

I want to write a python function to search a line, looking for a symbol, and if it is finds, then replace it by a value. The goal is to solve a `cgi` problem
So, the line looks like:

```
<h1><font color="#CC6600">%<br></font></h1>
```

and I wanted to check if % is on the page and then replace it is by a word, let's say, `Suffle`. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

use `str.replace()`:

```py
In [24]: strs="""<h1><font color="#CC6600">%<br></font></h1>"""

In [25]: strs.replace("%","Suffle")
Out[25]: '<h1><font color="#CC6600">Suffle<br></font></h1>'
```

To check the presence of a substring in a string we use `in`:

```
In [26]: "%" in strs
Out[26]: True
```